# Windows 8, Phpstorm 8, PHP 5.5 Xdebug not hitting breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug

I have recently bought a new computer. Previously I was running Windows 7 and PHPStorm 8 with PHP 5.5 (From WAMPServer) with XDebug 2.2.5. Everything was fine with this.

I am now on a new computer (Windows 8) with PHPStorm 8 and I cannot get XDebug to work correctly. I have **not** installed WAMPServer, but instead simply "lifted out" the PHP from my old hard disk. Maybe I **should** do this, but I wanted to avoid having the Apache server and MySQL as I don't want/need them on this computer.

Both installations (old and new) simply used the PHP Built-in web server for testing/debugging applications with.

I have been searching on Google and not found anyone else with a similar problem to mine neverless I have tried using multiple different snippets of configurations.

**What happens**

In my index.php I have added a phpinfo statement followed by die to simply spit out the PHP info and stop the application. I have put a breakpoint on the phpinfo line, and am expecting the IDE to pause here.

If I do Run > Debug > index.php (which launches a command line PHP session and simply executes index.php as a console app, the IDE **does** as expected and pauses at my breakpoint.

If I "Run" the Built-in web server, and hit localhost/index.php the IDE does **not** pause at my breakpoint although it does output the phpinfo.

It is behaving as though I have not pressed the telephone icon in PHPStorm, even though as I described in the console route it does pause at the breakpoint.

I confirm that the phpinfo output **does** indicate the XDebug is enabled and **does** reflect the settings in php.ini

**php.ini extract**

```
zend_extension = "c:/php/5.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/php/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0

xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_log="C:/php/xdebug.log"
```

phpinfo output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV8Rk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPf4o.png

I had even added in the xdebug.log bit to see what happens here, stopped and started the PHP Web server and tried the index.php call again, the log file was **not** created, so I have created it manually and granted full permissions in Windows. Tried the process again, and the file hasn't had any text added to it.

Text is added to the file, if I use that Run > Debug > index.php (console) route.

I think I am missing something ridiculous and obvious I just haven't a clue what it is.

Sorry for asking such a noob question, this is driving me mad!